# GeoServer GetFeatureInfo parameters

Tags: leaflet, wms, getfeatureinfo

I have a Leaflet map where on click I send GetFeatureInfo request to GeoServer, but the content of the HTML it returns is empty. I suppose I am computing parameters that I pass incorrectly, this is my request and how I compute parameters:

> http://localhost/geoserver/cite/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=cite:tbilisi&STYLES=&LAYERS=cite:tbilisi&exceptions=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=279&Y=212&SRS=EPSG:32638&WIDTH=886&HEIGHT=811&BBOX=44.77778434753419,41.703966325182236,44.815807342529304,41.72994572390489

Code

```
 L.tileLayer
      .wms("/geoserver/cite/wms", {
        layers: "cite:tbilisi",
        format: "image/png",
        transparent: true,
        srs: "EPSG:32638",

        maxZoom: 20,
        version: "1.1.0",
        zIndex: 444,
      })
      .addTo(that.mymap);

    that.mymap.on("click", (e) => {
      function Identify(e) {
        var BBOX = that.mymap.getBounds().toBBoxString();
        var WIDTH = that.mymap.getSize().x;
        var HEIGHT = that.mymap.getSize().y;
        var X = that.mymap.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).x;
        var Y = that.mymap.layerPointToContainerPoint(e.layerPoint).y;
        let URL = `/geoserver/cite/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=cite:tbilisi&STYLES=&LAYERS=cite:tbilisi&exceptions=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=${X}&Y=${Y}&SRS=EPSG:32638&WIDTH=${WIDTH}&HEIGHT=${HEIGHT}&BBOX=${BBOX}`;
        $.ajax({
          url: URL,
          datatype: "html",
          type: "GET",
          success: function (data) {
            L.popup().setLatLng(e.latlng).setContent(data).openOn(that.mymap);
          },
        });
      }
      Identify(e);
    });
```

Can someone spot what I am doing wrong?

BTW a request which does generate output **on the same area clicked through GeoServer Layer Preview** looks like this:

> http://10.28.7.8:8080/geoserver/cite/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetFeatureInfo&FORMAT=image/png&TRANSPARENT=true&QUERY_LAYERS=cite:tbilisi&STYLES=&LAYERS=cite:tbilisi&exceptions=application/vnd.ogc.se_inimage&INFO_FORMAT=text/html&FEATURE_COUNT=50&X=50&Y=50&SRS=EPSG:32638&WIDTH=101&HEIGHT=101&BBOX=482441.61821363633,4618994.366020213,482562.1103628997,4619114.8581694765

You see at least BBOX is different.

Comment: Normaly in a wms request you don't pass the data (`width`, `height`, `bbox`) of the map, normaly you pass the data of each single tile.

Comment: @FalkeDesign OP here, forgot to register. Like I said in the bottom of the question you can see an example of successful request generated by GeoServer on the same place clicked on the map. Just I don't understand what the difference is

Comment: It is exactly what I said, you create a request for the bbox of the complete map, and the working request only for the single tile

Comment: @FalkeDesign Can you show example how to do it correctly via leaflet? Also why are coordinates in BBOX different, e.g. the request from Geoserver has larger numbers in bbox like 482441 as compare to request from my app which has numbers like 41

Comment: @FalkeDesign This is doing something similar isn't it: https://gist.github.com/rclark/6908938#file-l-tilelayer-betterwms-js-L33 ?

Comment: yes exactly, this should work

Comment: @FalkeDesign No my point was that that code from Link and my code showed here are mostly same isn't it, that code also uses `this._map.getBounds().toBBoxString()`. What is the difference?

Comment: You are making the request against a tiled layer but using the whole map to calculate the click pixels so are probably clicking off tile - try this https://astuntechnology.github.io/osgis-ol3-leaflet/leaflet/05-WMS-INFO.html

Comment: @IanTurton The link you provided uses some `crs` variable for BBOX which I don't have in my app :(

Comment: @IanTurton That gist they refer to also seems to compute BBOX like I do: `this._map.getBounds().toBBoxString()` (Notice also the larger numbers from BBOX in query generated by GeoServer as posted in bottom of my question)

Comment: Your WMS layer is not in default Leaflet projection EPSG:3857, but in EPSG:32638 (UTM zone 38N). Are you using proj4.js to display this layer on your map?

Comment: @TomazicM Not sure I understood your question I am beginner in GIS. Are you referring to my leaflet APP or the Geoserver side? In my leaflet app in the question I showed ALL the code I have for adding the WMS layer on leaflet map (using `tileLayer` and `addTo`);  I don't use proj4.js

Comment: I'm referring to client side. If you use nonstandard projection, you have to define it first with the help of proj4Leaflet plugin (see https://github.com/kartena/Proj4Leaflet) and then use it when creating map by specifying it with `crs` option.

Comment: @TomazicM Maybe I can change projection on the GeoServer side to standard one, if that's easier option?

Comment: @TomazicM Or should I change projection on Leaflet side?

Comment: @TomazicM The docs say "In the GetMap operation the srs parameter is called crs in 1.3.0." - but if you look at the request that GeoServer made from my question (bottom) it says 1.1.1 I suppose, not?